# operator<< working w/ temp variable, but not directly with function call

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a `std::ostream operator<<` for a class.  I have a function that (taking advantage of ROV) returns instances of that class.

My operator works when I assign the result of that function call to a local variable, and then pass the local into `operator <<`, but NOT when I pass the result in directly.  What's going on here?

Simplified standalone example (test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class AnObject{
public: 
  AnObject(T value) : m_value(value) {}
  T getValue(){ return m_value; }
protected:
  T m_value;
};

template <class T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, AnObject<T> & obj )
{
  os << obj.getValue();
  return os;
}

AnObject<int> getObject()
{
  return AnObject<int>(5);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  // This doesn't compile
  std::cout << getObject() << std::endl;

  // This does....
  //auto obj = getObject();
  //std::cout << obj << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler command (g++ version 4.8.4 on Ubuntu):

g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp

Error:

```
test.cpp:26:26: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
```

Comment: You cant bind a temporary to a non const ref. Make your paramenter a const ref (meaning it should be `const AnObject<T> & obj`)

Comment: That does the trick. If you care at all about the made up internet points, I'll accept & upvote if you post this as an answer.

Comment: I reached 10k, I no longer care about the internet points :)

Answer (score -1):

```
AnObject<int> getObject()
{
  return AnObject<int>(5);
}
```

This function above is your error. Why? Because it's used as a part of an rvalue expression, which is not an lvalue.

In C++, `lvalues` sort of represent the "containers" that hold actual values. `rvalues` refer to these "actual" values. A good example:

```
int i = 5; // i is the lvalue, 5 is the rvalue.
// 5 by itself is not a variable, but i has the rvalue of 5 but the lvalue of i.
```

The `<<` operators wants an actual object instead of a value of it--in other words, it should have a "home" and be stored somewhere.

So either make another overload that takes a `&&`, which means it can take values that may not "live" anywhere (e.g. expressions) or require the values that come in to be lvalues (references to real objects). A good option is to use `const T&`, to which rvalues can be cast.